# Populate a RecyclerView using SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-database

My RecyclerView was working fine when i populated it from a local database using SQLiteHelper, but now i want to populate it using an external database located in my assets folder by using SQLiteAssetHelper, so i followed the example from this [Github SQLiteAssetHelper example](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) but i think that the SimpleCursorAdapter() method is compatible ListView but not with the RecyclerView as it gives me an "Incompatible Type" IDE error.

Is their a way around this or should i convert my RecyclerView to a ListView? Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataSource mDataSource;
    List<Facility> facilityList = DataProvider.facilityList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDataSource = new DataSource(this);
        mDataSource.open();                             // Open database
        mDataSource.seedDatabase(facilityList);

        List<Facility> listFromDB = mDataSource.getAllItems();
        FacilitiesAdapter adapter = new FacilitiesAdapter(this, listFromDB);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.displayActivityRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }   // End of onCreate()


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDataSource.close();                        // Close database connection when application is
    }                                               // paused to prevent database leaks.

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDataSource.open();                         // Open database connection when application is resumed
    }
}
```

SQLiteHelper Class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_FILE_NAME = "health.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_FILE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(FacilitiesTable.SQL_CREATE);         // Execute SQL_CREATE statement;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(FacilitiesTable.SQL_DELETE);         // delete old database
        onCreate(db);                                   // Create new database
    }
}
```

Comment: "My RecyclerView was working fine when i populated it from a local database using SQLiteHelper" -- you were not using `SimpleCursorAdapter` there. So, if it "was working fine", stick with that code, swapping out your `SQLiteOpenHelper` for a `SQLiteAssetHelper`. Otherwise, create your own `RecyclerView.Adapter` that uses your `Cursor` as its data source.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your reply again :) But i need to use the external database, or somehow copy the database file into my /data/data/package/databases folder, which would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code that "was working fine with i populated it from a local database using SQLiteHelper".

Comment: @CommonsWare , I have edited the code.

Comment: So, just replace `extends SQLiteOpenHelper` with `extends SQLiteAssetHelper`, delete the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods, and adjust the constructor to supply what `SQLiteAssetHelper` needs. If this code worked with a class that `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`, it will work with a class that `extends SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I don't know what to say, after 4 days of hopelessness i was about to give up. It finally worked thanks to you. You solved me a problem of massive proportions. I thank you greatly, but just thanking you is just not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLiteAssetHelper` is a plug-and-play replacement for `SQLiteOpenHelper`, as `SQLiteAssetHelper` itself extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

So, given code that works with a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, all you need to do is:

- Change that subclass to extend `SQLiteAssetHelper`
- Remote the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods
- Adjust the call to the superclass constructor, if needed

Then, package your database in `assets/`, per [the documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#usage), and you should be good to go.

Any code that worked when you were extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` should continue to work now that you are extending `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the database from Assets folder to "default" location using this method:

```
public final String path = "/data/data/YourPackageName/databases/";
    public final String Name = "DataBaseName.db";

    public void copydatabase() throws IOException {

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(path + Name);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        InputStream myInput = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("DataBaseName.db");
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();

    }
```

Than just call  :

```
copydatabase()
```

And surround with try/catch.